# Know selected tkEnumeration from a tkSet

Tags: delphi, rtti

I need to do a function to know all published properties and their values from an Object. I have done a function that do this except for the tkSet properties. I can get the tkEnumeration elements from the tkSet but I don't know the way to know if a tkEnumeration is selected.

Here my function

```
  procedure TForm1.GetObjectProperties(Obj: TObject; List: TStrings;
    Level: Integer);

    function GetSubPropObject(Obj: TObject; APropName: string): TObject;
    var
      PropInfo: PPropInfo;
    begin
      Result := nil;
      try
        PropInfo := GetPropInfo(Obj, APropName);
        if Assigned(PropInfo) and (PropInfo.PropType^.Kind in [tkClass]) then
        begin
          Result := GetObjectProp(Obj, PropInfo);
        end;
      except
        on E: Exception do
          List.Add(Obj.ClassName + ' ----- ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;

    // ==> with this procedure I obtains the tkEnumeration elements from a tkSet
    procedure GetSetInformation(AOrdTypeInfo: PTypeInfo; Space: string);
    var
      OrdTypeData: PTypeData;
      TypeNameStr: string;
      TypeKindStr: string;
      MinVal, MaxVal: Integer;
      i: integer;
    begin
      Space := Space + '     ';
       // Get the TTypeData pointer
      OrdTypeData := GetTypeData(AOrdTypeInfo);
       // Get the type name string
      //TypeNameStr := string(AOrdTypeInfo.Name);
       // Get the type kind string
      //TypeKindStr := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TTypeKind), Integer(AOrdTypeInfo^.Kind));

      MinVal := OrdTypeData^.MinValue;
      MaxVal := OrdTypeData^.MaxValue;

      if AOrdTypeInfo^.Kind = tkSet then
        GetSetInformation(OrdTypeData^.CompType^, Space);

      if AOrdTypeInfo^.Kind = tkEnumeration then
        for i := MinVal to MaxVal do
          List.Add(Space + GetEnumName(AOrdTypeInfo, i));
    end;
  var
    ctx: TRttiContext;
    rt: TRttiType;
    prop: TRttiProperty;
    Tmp: string;
    i: Integer;
  begin
    if not Assigned(Obj) or not Assigned(List) then Exit;

    Tmp := '';
    for i := 0 to (Level * 10) do
      Tmp := Tmp + ' ';

    ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
    try
      rt := ctx.GetType(Obj.ClassType);

      for prop in rt.GetProperties do
      begin
        if not prop.IsWritable then
          Continue;
        if TRttiInstanceType(prop.PropertyType).TypeKind in [tkMethod, tkPointer] then
          Continue;
        if prop.Visibility <> mvPublished then
          Continue;

        try
          //List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ' + prop.GetValue(Obj).ToString);
          case TRttiInstanceType(prop.PropertyType).TypeKind of
            tkInteger, tkInt64:
              List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ' + IntToStr(prop.GetValue(Obj).AsInteger));
            tkFloat:
              List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ' + FloatToStr(prop.GetValue(Obj).AsExtended));
            tkChar, tkString, tkWChar, tkLString, tkWString, tkUString:
              List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ' + prop.GetValue(Obj).AsString);
            tkEnumeration:
              List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ' + GetEnumName(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo, Ord(prop.GetValue(Obj).Kind)));
            tkSet:
              begin
                List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ');
                GetSetInformation(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo, Tmp);
              end;
            else
              List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + ') ' + ' --- ' + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TTypeKind), Ord(TRttiInstanceType(prop.PropertyType).TypeKind)));
          end;
        except
          List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' ERROR TypeCast');
        end;

        if TRttiInstanceType(prop.PropertyType).TypeKind = tkClass then
          GetObjectProperties(GetSubPropObject(Obj, prop.Name), List, Level + 1);
      end;
    finally
      ctx.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't quite fit with the format of your output as currently written, but you can obtain a string representation of the values that are members of a set by simply using the **ToString** method of the value itself.

So, where you currently have:

```
       tkSet:
          begin
            List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ');
            GetSetInformation(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo, Tmp);
          end;
```

Which in the case of the default **Anchors** on a form, for example, would output:

```
Anchors:
    akLeft
    akTop
    akRight
    akBottom
```

You could instead write:

```
       tkSet:
          begin
            List.Add(Tmp + prop.Name + ' (' + string(prop.GetValue(Obj).TypeInfo.Name) + '): ' + prop.GetValue(Obj).ToString);
          end;
```

For the same default values of the **Anchors** property on a form, this will now output:

```
Anchors: [akLeft,akTop]
```

If you need to convert to the actual enum values or present them in some other format it should be a relatively straightforward exercise to extract the individual member names from this string and use them to obtain the values or present the data in whatever format you need.

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation of the expected output format. This is not exactly that I search, but I think I can use it to determine what I want. I search a way to "simulate" object inspector. For Anchors example, I want that return akLeft: true or akTop: false

Comment: As explained in the answer, I was aware this was not the format in your posted code, but how you present the results is up to you.  You already knew how to get all the enum member names applicable to the set.  Now you know also how to (easily) get the names of only those members which are in the set (which was the question).  The rest is just string parsing and formatting.  :)